# What does a chat room load in the background while it displays 'Loading the room. Please wait'?

Tags: discussion, chat

What does a chat room load in the background while it displays a box saying 'Loading the room. Please wait'?

Is it just a delay softener, or is it still not ready in that moment?

Comment: Disable javascript and see what happens. Or rather doesn't happen

Comment: so true.. This warning appears if you disable it 'Welcome to the chat! Unfortunately, you have JavaScript disabled, and thus this chat will not work. If you would like to participate, please enable JavaScript in your browser and reload this page. '

Comment: I just don't understand why it was done with javascript. Isn't mobile support a concern?

Comment: Yeah it is a concern and it is annoying mobile devices these days still don't support javascript ;-)

Comment: alright :/ couldn't it be made as Facebook does? Just a check to determine if the device supports javascript, if not fallback to some server side technology.

Answer (score 3):

The chat UI is almost entirely JavaScript based with the application data provided by websocket and AJAX calls.

So, when the page loads, before the websocket and AJAX calls kick in, there isn't much to see and there is a simple 'loading' message displayed. Once all relevant data has been loaded over the socket and the right AJAX calls have completed, the loading message is hidden.

In other words, it's a delay softener.

Comment: in particular I think it's just involving the messages, as I see the sidebar already fully loaded --> http://i.imgur.com/xyOLcy4.png

Comment: @slowbanned: That is the loading message included in the page HTML, shown until the websockets and AJAX responses have come in.

Comment: Understand. I didn't contradict you, just wanted to add that detail :)